# why my sql query slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a view which join from 4 tables (tb_user is 200 row, tb_transaction is 250.000 row, tb_transaction_detail is 250.000 row, tb_ms_location is 50 row),
when i render with datatables serverside, it's take 13 secons. even when I filtering it.

I don't know why it's take too long...

here my sql query

```
    CREATE VIEW `vw_cashback` AS

    SELECT 
        `tb_user`.`nik` AS `nik`,
        `tb_user`.`full_name` AS `nama`,
        `tb_ms_location`.`location_name` AS `lokasi`,
        `tb_transaction`.`date_transaction` AS `tanggal_setor`,
        sum(CASE WHEN `tb_transaction_detail`.`vehicle_type`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `mobil`,
        sum(CASE WHEN `tb_transaction_detail`.`vehicle_type`=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `motor`,
        sum(CASE WHEN `tb_transaction_detail`.`vehicle_type`=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `truck`,
        sum(CASE WHEN `tb_transaction_detail`.`vehicle_type`=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `speda`,
        sum(`tb_transaction_detail`.`total`) AS `total_global`,
        (sum(`tb_transaction_detail`.`total`) * 0.8) AS `total_user`,
        (sum(`tb_transaction_detail`.`total`) * 0.2) AS `total_tgr`,
        ((sum(`tb_transaction_detail`.`total`) * 0.2) / 2) AS `total_cashback`,
        (curdate() - cast(`tb_user`.`created_at` AS date)) AS `status`


    FROM `tb_user`
        JOIN `tb_transaction` ON `tb_user`.`id` = `tb_transaction`.`user_id`
        JOIN `tb_transaction_detail` ON `tb_transaction`.`id` = `tb_transaction_detail`.`transaction_id`
        JOIN `tb_ms_location` ON `tb_ms_location`.`id` = `tb_transaction`.`location_id`

    GROUP BY 
        `tb_user`.`id`,
        `tb_transaction`.`date_transaction`,
        `tb_user`.`nik`,
        `tb_user`.`full_name`,
        `tb_user`.`created_at`,
        `tb_ms_location`.`location_name`
```

thanks

Comment: Use your database's "explain" functionality to get it to tell you how the query will be optimized.

Comment: I use mysql as my database, is my data big.?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all columns used in joins?

Comment: It is  not particularly big.  But a database should be able to query big tables *provided* that the query and / or schema are well designed and suitably optimized.  Hence ... use "explain".

Comment: no, does index auto increment is influencing query process.?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: No, it doesn't influence it.  Have you used "explain" yet?   It seems like you are still using guesswork as your means of solving the problem.

Comment: It would make barely any difference, but why do you have `* 0.2) / 2` rather than `* 0.1` or `/ 10`?

Answer (score 1):

The unfiltered query must be slow, because it takes all records from all tables, joins and aggregates them.

But you say the view is still slow when you filter. The question is: How do you filter? As you are aggregating by user, location and transaction date, it should be one of these. However, you don't have the user ID or the transaction ID in your result list. This doesn't feel natural and I'd suggest you add them, so a query like

```
select * from vw_cashback where user_id = 5
```

or

```
select * from vw_cashback where transaction_id = 12345
```

would be possible.

As is, you'd have to filter by location name or user nik / name. So if you want it thus, then create Indexes for the lookup:

```
CREATE idx_location_name ON tb_ms_location(location_name, id)
CREATE idx_user_name ON tb_user(full_name, id)
CREATE idx_user_nik ON tb_user(nik, id)
```

The latter two can even be turned into covering indexs (i.e. indexes containing all columns used in the query) that may still speed up the process:

```
CREATE idx_user_name ON tb_user(nik, id, full_name, created_at);
CREATE idx_user_nik ON tb_user(full_name, id, nik, created_at);
```

As for the access via index, you also may want covering indexes:

```
CREATE idx_location_id ON tb_ms_location(id, location_name)
CREATE idx_user_id ON tb_user(id, nik, full_name, created_at);
```